# Inverse of a (singly) non-central F variable

Tags: distributions, f-distribution

It is known that if $X \sim F_{\nu_1,\nu_2}$ (F distribution with degrees of freedom $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$), then $X^{-1} \sim F_{\nu_2,\nu_1}$.

Is there any known similar result for $X \sim F_{\nu_1,\nu_2, \delta}$ (noncentral F distribution, with d.f. $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$, and noncentrality parameter $\delta$)?

---

EDIT

$F_{\nu_1,\nu_2, \delta}$ can be expressed as the ratio $\, \left( \chi^2_{\nu_1}(\delta)  / \nu_1 \right) / \left(  \chi^2_{\nu_2}(0)/ \nu_2 \right) \,$, where $\chi^2_{\nu}(\delta)$ is the noncentral $\chi^2$ distribution with $\nu$ d.f. and noncentrality parameter $\delta$. When $\delta=0$, we obtain the (centred) $\chi^2$ distribution.

So, is there a known expression for the distribution of $\, F_{\nu_1,\nu_2, \delta}^{-1} \sim \left( \chi^2_{\nu_2}(0)  / \nu_2 \right) / \left(  \chi^2_{\nu_1}(\delta)/ \nu_1 \right) \, $, or can it be derived somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NoncentralF-Distribution.html, the (singly) noncentral $F$ distribution is a particular case of the doubly noncentral $F$ distribution $F_{\nu_1, \nu_2}(\delta_1, \delta_2) \sim \left( \chi^2_{\nu_1}(\delta_1) \right) / \left( \chi^2_{\nu_2}(\delta_2) \right)$.

That is to say, if $X \sim F_{\nu_1, \nu_2}(\delta) \equiv F_{\nu_1, \nu_2}(\delta, 0)$, then it is clear than $\boxed{X^{-1} \sim F_{\nu_2, \nu_1}(0 , \delta)}$ (which is said to be a *special case* of the doubly noncentered $F$ distribution in the reference above).